# How do I upload raster tiles to Carto?

Tags: raster, carto, tiles

I converted a .tif file into a tileset using the gdal2tiles plugin on QGIS. The resulting files are a bunch of .png files, .html files and a .xml file. I zipped these and tried uploading them to Carto but got the error that the file types were not supported.

What am I doing wrong? How does one upload these tiles?

Answer (score 5):

CARTO is a location intelligence platform aimed to store vector datasets you want to visualize and analyze. CARTO does not support uploading tilesets. You need to publish them elsewhere on a static web service hosting and then if they fit the technical requirements (projection and so on) you'll be able to add them as a basemap to your CARTO visualization.

Answer (score 2):

You can't import directly file formats such as .png, .html or .xml to CARTO due to those are not supported formats (In [this section](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/importing-geospatial-data#supported-geospatial-data-formats) of the documentation of CARTO, you can find detailed information about the supported files to import to CARTO)

In order to add the custom tileset to be added as a basemap to CARTO they would need to be stored in a web server. So you can add them to the map by adding a new basemap using a URL.